# Is it possible to acces a property within a function through a callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback, local-variables

So I was wondering if it was possible to acces a local variable within a function through a callback function. For example I could be able to acces the '  i ' variable in the function's for loop.

```
function forWithAction(r,callback){
  for(let i = 0; i < r; i++){
    callback();
  }
}

forWithAction(5,function(){
  console.log(i);
});
```

I got no luck so far but i'm really optimistic on this possibility, so I wonder if there is anyone out there that can give me clues or answers.

Comment: No, that's not possible. You could, however, pass in the value to the callback: `function forWithAction(r,callback){
  for(let i = 0; i < r; i++){
    callback(i);
  }
}

forWithAction(5,function(i){
  console.log(i);
});`

Comment: a very nice solution to be honest. Thanks for the reply JLRishe!

Comment: `i` is not a property, it's a local variable. And the only way to access it is to pass its value to the `callback` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code it is possible, but within the function call back, you want to pass every variable you might want to access into the function. It;s how map, filter and reduce work.

```js
function forWithAction(r,callback){
  for(let i = 0; i < r; i++){
    callback(i, r);
  }
}
//iVal and rVal are just place holders for i and r that I'm passing into this function
forWithAction(5,function(iVal, rVal){
  console.log(iVal);
});
```

**An Example with Map**

```js
function Map(arr, callback)
{
  let output = [];
  let secretVariable = 'I\'m hidden inside :D';
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
  {
    //I'm passing 4 values into my callback. So any call back I create
    //I can access these 4 values
    let val = callback(arr[i], i, arr, secretVariable)
    output.push(val);
  }
  return output;
}

let myArray = [2, 5, 1, 8, 9, 3, 2];

Map(myArray, function(val, ind, arr, secret) {
  console.log('__ARRAY_VALUE__: ', val);
  console.log('__INDEX__(i) :', ind);
  console.log(secret);
  return val;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution and the explenation. It just already reliefs me how I can dry code so many things with this function.

Comment: Yep. Glad it worked. Mark as answered if this answers your question :D